# Can we trigger multiple agents/Listerns from a single TFS build

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I have two different application installed on two different machines/servers. I have done the automation using C# of both the application, they are integrated at data level and i have to trigger a single build and my scripts would randomly execution on both machines. Both are desktop applications.

Now the problem is can we configure two agents with single TFS build installed on two different machines, like my some of the scripts would run on Machine A and there would be a listener A, and in the same build some of the scripts would run on machine B where there is other application and i would surely install the agent as well.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Configure multiple agents in an agent pool.
2. Choose Multi-agent option in Execution plan of Phase
3. Choose Based on number of tests and agents in Batch tests box of Visual Studio test

Related article: [Test batching options with VSTest task](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/14/test-batching-options-with-vstest-task/)